# How can work my java program? (ArrayList)

Tags: java, class, oop, permutation, combinatorics

I'd like to make a combinatorics calculator in java, but I'm very beginner. I have a class, its name is permutation. I declared an array list, but I can't upload content in that. After that the program has ran, the array list will be empty. Why?

```
package combinatorics;
import java.util.*;

public class Permutation {

    private int num;
    protected ArrayList<Integer> szamok = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Permutation(int number) {
        this.num = number;
    }

    protected void makeArrayList() {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.num+1; i++) {
            this.szamok.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permutation perm = new Permutation(5);
        perm.getNumbers();
    }
```

Comment: You never call `makeArrayList()`, and since it's private, no one outside the class can call it. To make matters worse, the constructor is also private.

Comment: The constructor was't private. :D I changed accidentally. But if the constructor is not private, the arraylist will be empty as well.

Comment: @Kovoliver You're missing the point - the fact that `makeArrayList()` is private is also a problem. It won't ever be called, so of *course* your ArrayList is always empty. Making the constructor public won't help you with that problem in the least. Also, please edit your question to show where you actually use this class as that's important to being able to answer this.

Comment: Where do you hope to populate the list? `makeArrayList()` is never called.

Comment: Did you meant to include a call to `makeArrayList()` in the constructor?

Comment: Where do you define the `getNumbers()` method? Can you show that code as well? Does that call `makeArrayList()`?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this works:

```
package combinatorics;
import java.util.*;

public class Permutation {

    private final int num;
    protected ArrayList<Integer> szamok = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int egyszam;

    public Permutation(int number) {
        this.num = number;
    }

    protected void makeArrayList() {
        for (int i = 1; i < this.num+1; i++) {
            this.szamok.add(i);
        }
    }

   public void getNumbers() {
        for (int i = 0; i < szamok.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(szamok.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

With this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permutation perm = new Permutation(10);
        perm.makeArrayList();
        perm.getNumbers();
        launch(args);
    }
```

Thank you for the ansewrs to my sptupid question. :) I'm really a beginner, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is being added to the ArrayList is because the function `makeArrayList` is never called. Another thing wrong is that your constructor is also private, which is unnecessary and means you cannot create an instance of that class. You can call `makeArrayList` in your constructor, or add items separately, outside of the Permutation class.

You can also add items to your ArrayList by doing:

```
Permutation p = new Permutation(num);
p.szamok.add(num);
```

Then

```
System.out.println(p.szamok.toString();
```

would return

`[num]`

Comment: `szamok` is protected.

Comment: The problem with that is? Permutation is probably in the same package, meaning it can be accessed within the Main class.